# Split git branch into separate repo

Tags: git

I have the following git tree :

```
branch v2 =>                    / --- [lots of work] --- [new version] --- ref_d
                               /
  root --- ref_a --- ... --- ref_b (project reset)
             \
branch v1 =>  \ --- [some works] --- ref_c
```

As v1 and v2 are really different, two different team will maintain v1 and v2, I would like two separate branch two to different git repository as :

```
repo_v1 : from root to ref_c
repo_v2 : from ref_b to ref_d
```

How should I do this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following assumes you have your two separate new repos set up as remotes named `repo_v1` and `repo_v2`.

The v1 branch is easy:

```
git push repo_v1 ref_c:v1
```

The v2 branch isn't that hard:

```
git checkout --orphan v2 ref_b
git cherry-pick ref_b..ref_d
git push repo_v2 v2
```

(`git checkout --orphan <branchname> <startpoint>` creates an entirely new history that starts from the specified point but doesn't have any of that commit's parents.)

Comment: Got `fatal: A branch named XXX already exists` When I retried with a new branch name, this created a commit-less branch. Then the second command, `git cherry-pick a..b` failed too (commit your new branch first). So I did commit current state but it would be better imho to make an empty commit as step 0. To add another repo : `git remote add new_repo git@xxxx` (cf. any documentation). And then i pushed and it worked perfectly, I got the targeted branch in my dedicated repo with commits history.

Answer (score 1):

According to project setup I would rather

1) create new repo for `v1`

```
git checkout v1
git remote add v1_repo git@gitlab.com:andrej/project-v1.git
git push v1_repo v1:master
```

2a) merge `v2` into `master` branch.

```
git checkout master
git merge v2
```

2b) if you insist on making 2 new projects then you can create new project from the newly merged master:

```
git remote add v2_repo git@gitlab.com:andrej/project-v2.git
git push v2_repo master
```

3) You can tidy up original repo by deleting v1 and v2 branches:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D v1
git branch -d v2
```

You have to use `-D` for force delete branch `v1` here because `v1` branch it was not merged.